# How do you make function work inside each sub-list

Tags: python

I need to create a function that returns the prime numbers of n as a list and then print the prime numbers of that list as well, making a sub-list. For example, if n = 10, the output should be this

Output:

```
[[2,[2]],[3,[3]],[4,[2,2]],[5,[5]],[6,[2,3]],[7,[7]],[8,[2,2,2]],[9,[3,3]],[10,[2,5]]]
```

For now I have this function:

```
L = []
P = []
S = []
for x in range(2,n+1,1):
    S = []
    S.append(x)
    S.append([])
    L.append(S)
r = S[0]
for x in range(2,r+1):
    while r % x == 0:
        P.append(x)
        r = r//x
        S[1] = P
        print(S[0])
```

However, it only prints the prime number of the item in the last sub-list, and my question is how do I make my function work on every single sub-list of the list, not just the last one.

Comment: I suggest separate your problem into two problems. First try to decompose any given number and then use that to struct a list in correct form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the last step for all sub-lists

```
n = 10

L = []
for x in range(2,n+1,1):
    P = []
    S = []
    S.append(x)
    S.append([])
    L.append(S)
    r = S[0]
    for x in range(2,r+1):
        while r % x == 0:
            P.append(x)
            r = r//x
            S[1] = P

print(L)
```

Output

```
[[2, [2]], [3, [3]], [4, [2, 2]], [5, [5]], [6, [2, 3]], [7, [7]], [8, [2, 2, 2]], [9, [3, 3]], [10, [2, 5]]]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding. I'm really new at this stuff, could you explain further please? Thank you:)

Comment: @CynthiaSustaita I just changed the indentation. In your code you first fill the list `L` and then for the last `S` you print the prime numbers. In my code `L` is filled and for each `S` the prime numbers are printed.